# Binding dataframe rows with both characters and integers

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have two sets of data, 2 obs of 7 variables.

I am trying to generate a set of data (dataframe) that is the combination of the two sets I currently have.

For example the goal is to have a single set of data that would be, 4 obs of 7 variables. Having simply added the second data set's rows to the others underneath. Basically just trying to create a larger table with more rows made up of the ones I have.

The things I have tried include installing dplyr:

```
rbind(df1,df2)

rbind(df1,df2, .is=NULL)
```

I had an error about:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous name
```

I belive this is due to generating my data from a csv file which contained headers for my first data set as the column headers, and the second data set had different headers as it was read from further down in the file so the headers were x1,x1.1 etc...

so I tried unnamed() which also failed.

then I tried

```
bind_rows(df1,df2)
```

but it gave me a 4x14 data set instead.
I also was getting errors elsewhere along the lines of

> Error: not compatible with STRSXP

I think the issue lies in that my data frames might be stored as lists, as well as the data having some columns as characters and some as numbers.

Comment: Just do `names(df2) <- names(df1)` before using `rbind` or `bind_rows`. This assumes that columns in both dataframes are in same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm getting it right, but you might struggle with different colnames and data types.

What you can do:

1) `colnames(df1)` and `colnames(df2)`: do you have the same colnames?

2) Then, try `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` and see if there are differences.

3) In case your dataframes are stored as list convert them back do dataframes.

**ad 1)** In case the colnames are the problem you can do:

```
colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1)
rbind(df1,df2)
```

**ad 2)** If it's still not working and the datatypes are different, make them match each other and try to bind the rows again.

**ad 3)** If your dataframes are lists and thus it's not working try:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(bind_rows(df1), bind_rows(df2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem you have different data types in your data frames. A solution could then be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

# Example data sets
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1L, 2L))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c("1", "2"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Solution
df1 <- df1 %>% retype()
df2 <- df2 %>% retype()

bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Which gives a merged data frame:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
      a
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     1
4     2
```